# How to Auto resize UIButton height and width in IOS?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a UIButton which has back ground image and text. I am setting the UIButton frame height and width using code. My application allows the user to change the language.

Please provide a best solution for following problem, 
- On Language change, UIButton image not adjusting its height and width based on translated text. How to adjust the UIButton image height and width of image? Is it anything like wrap image based text?

FYI, I have around 40 strings to be adjusted, looking for simple and best way to do this.

Comment: just try to play with UIEdgeInsets for title and Image of button with respect to text of Button title if nothing works, because setting Edge Insets will definitely work

Answer (score 1):

After changing the text ... etc, use this:

```
 [myButton sizeToFit];
```